# when importing a model to unity from blender, i get odd material results

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

i imported my blender backrooms model to unity, and i got a wierd mess, [this is the model in unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCfKT.png) , when its in blender it looks exactly as intended, and even when i render a image of the model in blender all the textures look like they should,[this is the model in blender, not a rendered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KIXX.png), ive browsed countless "solutions" and i cant find one that applies to mine, i have tried  changing unity import settings, extracting both materials and images, and so on, nothing makes the materials look proper, my guess is that its not accounting for UV mapping junk so its stretching the image so far that it becomes blurred beyond recognitiion, if anybody can help me out it would be much appreciated, also just a side note but i dont think the displacement maps work in unity like they do in blender

edit: the model has multiple objects, the floor ceiling and walls are all 3 seperate objects

edit again: [here is the node layout for the floor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lZjJ.png), every other node layout for the walls and ceiling is just the floors layout but without a displacement map on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a minute since I've used Unity. But without looking at the blender file, I would suspect that it could maybe be that there's two UVs on your model, and Unity is using the wrong one. I believe Unity uses the first UV Map for texture info, while the others are used for lightmap info. If that's the case, just delete the wrong one in your model. Hopefully that helps!

**Edit (more info):**  I created a basic model with walls, ceiling, and floor. The walls, and ceiling only have a UV Map called `UVMap`. However, the floor has two UV Maps: `UVMap` and `UVMap.001`. Like so:[image: TwoUV]

Now, if I click on that little camera icon next to the UVMap/UVMap.001 you will possibly see the overall size of the bricks change. If so, delete the wrongly scaled UV Map so you only have one UV Map in that window. After that, I would just ensure all your UV Maps are called the same on your other meshes, which is typically `UVMap` as default. You will also want to be sure all of your images are being mapped by UV, not Object or Generated as Unity cannot use that information. From there you should be good to go!

Comment: alright ill check it out, thanks

Comment: hmm... i looked into it and i dont think i exactly know what a UV is, i have a hunch that when talking about a UV your referring to the map that is created when UV unwrapping, though i am new to blender so you may have to explain, also just a detail that i will add to the question: the model has multiple objects, the floor ceiling and walls are all 3 seperate objects

Comment: @chillco.manager Okay, not a problem! I edited my answer to try and provide a more in-depth answer. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: oh so thats how you see all the UV maps! thanks ill check it out!

Comment: well i dont have additional UV maps on any of my objects from what i can see, kinda frustrating cuz i see everybody else easily making texture tiling lol

Comment: i will update my question with my node layout and see if that might help

Comment: Ohhh, okay, I see what you did wrong now. Your texture coordinate is set to Object instead of UV. Unity doesn't know how to use Object mapping, it only uses UV Mapping. So you will want to switch the node to UV Map and then fix your UV's on your object. After that you should be set! You will also want to change your texture mode from `box` to `flat`.

Comment: oh ill try that, thanks

Comment: but i need box because of how the texture tiling works

Comment: tried it with flat and it was really hard to get all 3 dimensions with thier own unique scaling because obviously images are flat and the object is 3D

Comment: actually maybe UV will work with flat

Comment: nope, tried it with all three objects, they have a very smeared appearance only fixed by setting it to object and box, though settings other than object may work

Comment: i can tell this will be a while til it gets solved...

Comment: @chillco.manager did you try UV mapping your object as well? You will need to have it UV mapped in order for it to work. There are a ton of tutorials on youtube for UV mapping in blender. But for a simple  floor, walls, and ceiling explanation is select all of your meshes (Your floor, walls, ceiling), apply size (CTRL+A, apply size), go into edit mode, hit "U" and a menu will pop up, select `Cube Project` (make sure your in front, side, or top view before doing this). Once that is done, your object(s) now contain a UV Map that shouldn't be skewed. From there you can scale your UVs.

Comment: well this is a bit late, but yes i did UV map my object, i believe, ive moved onto diffrent projects so this is no longer a issue